# monaco-editor typescript not providing suggestions

Tags: typescript, monaco-editor

In monaco-editor if you try to use a union type as a parameter of a function it does not provide you any suggestions. Doing the same in vscode provides you with the suggestions. Is there something I need to enable in monaco to get the same functionality?

It does provide the correct checking and errors, however the suggestions seem to be missing.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Or is this not supported in monaco-editor?

Examples below:

```js
type Test = {
    choice1: "A" | "B" | "C";
    choice2: "X" | "Y" | "Z";
}

function test<T extends keyof Test>(t: T, s: Test[T]) {

}

test("choice1", "")
```

vscode:

[image: In VSCode]

monaco-editor:

[image: In Monaco]

I've also tried with a simple union type and the same
[Simple in Monaco](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQWFl.png)

```js
type Test2 = "something" | "somethingelse"

function test2(t: Test2) {

}

test2("")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This must be a simple mistake. It works pretty well in my application and in the monaco-editor [playground](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html):

[image]

Comment: Oh, I had tried that in the playground yesterday and it did not show the list, will try again shortly

Comment: Ah ok, it does if I press ctrl+space to trigger the suggestions, but it doesn't automatically like it does in vscode which is why I thought it wasnt working. I was expecting it to display as soon as I added the first quote which is when it triggers in vscode

Comment: Then it's probably only a matter of defining the correct trigger chars. Do you have a custom completion provider implemented? The monaco.CompletionItemProvider allows to define trigger chars in a member var called `triggerCharacters`.

Comment: We do have a copy of the monaco-typescript package as we have some changes which we needed specific to us, and adding the trigger characters there seems to have worked thanks for you help, had forgotten about the trigger characters